# How to get the root directory of wordpress in css

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I get the root directory in css of wordpress?

My css is this:

```
#bg{
display: block;
background: url('/assets/images/_userfiles/bg_1.png') no-repeat center center;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

I tought this would link to the root of wordpress folder, but it doesn't so how can I possibly get this right?

My assets map is in the very root of the wordpress folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS you used gives you the domain root.

So if your domain is www.site.com your css tries to request:

**www.site.com/assets/images/_userfiles/bg_1.png**

files mentioned in CSS when not used with an absolute path as you have done are relative to your css stylesheet file.

so, of you have your css file in:

www.site.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css

And you have your files in:

www.site.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/images/_userfiles/bg_1.png

you only need to remove your first '/' from your your css `url()`;

```
#bg
   {
   display: block;
   background: url('assets/images/_userfiles/bg_1.png') no-repeat center center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
```

**Recap**

The base url is relative to your css file.

To go up one directory relative to your css file use `url(../path/to/file/that/is/one/directory/up/from/your/css/file);`

So, just examine in your ftp explorer which directory structure your css file is located and figure out your way to your assets folder.

You can use as many `../../../` you wish. If the max is reached the browser will default to the url of the site as if you had used a '/' to start your url.

Comment: I have used 4 ../ and have reached the correct path, thank you!